# Capture nth field bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have data in a file test.txt in below format.

```
abc,123,mno,xyz,1234
mno,123,abc,rpt,pqr,2345
xyz,456,uyt,rtp,rto,
```

I want to capture the 3rd field which I am able to achieve using

```
var=`awk  -F, '{print $3}' test.txt | sed "s/^[ \t]*//"`
```

I have run into a issue where 3rd field can be either "mno" or "abc,rpt".

If I use the above logic I get output as

```
mno
abc
uyt
```

But I want output as

```
 mno
 abc,rpt    
 uyt,rtp
```

Any suggestions.

Regards

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for **that** sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Just guessing: if a line ends with a comma, you want to get Field 3 and 4, right? Try `awk  -F, '{s=($0 ~ /,$/)?$3","$4:$3; print s}'`

Comment: Hi . I have edited the question . I am sorry I was not very clear at start.

Comment: I.. do not understand, the output you are getting is the 3rd field. `3rd field can be either "mno" or "abc,rpt"` what is the logic? How do _you_ know that the 3rd field consists of two fields??

Comment: Ok, `awk  -F, '{s=(NF==6?$3","$4:$3); print s}'`? If there are 6 fields, concat 3 and 4, else get the 3rd only. See https://ideone.com/jUr64k

Comment: Yes. Ideally there should be only 5 fields only ( 4 commas ) in any line . But if there are more than 4 commas then 3rd and 4th field should be concat.

Comment: What's the `| sed "s/^[ \t]*//"` for? You don't need it even if your fields do start with spaces - then you'd just include those in the FS setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sh
awk  -F, '{s=(NF==6?$3","$4:$3); print s}'
```

That is, if there are 6 fields, concatenate the third and fourth, else get the third field value only.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/jUr64k):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='abc,123,mno,xyz,1234
mno,123,abc,rpt,pqr,2345
xyz,456,uyt,rtp,rto,'
awk  -F, '{s=(NF==6?$3","$4:$3); print s}'  <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
mno
abc,rpt
uyt,rtp
```

Answer (score 1):

You need not to save output into a variable and then print it(its not required in here), we can simply use ternary operators in `print` function of `awk` itself, like as follows:

```
awk -F, '{print (NF==6?$3","$4:$3)}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, setting field separator as `,` and using `print` statement of `awk` here, where checking condition if `NF`(number of fields in current line) is `6` then print 3rd and 4th fields separated with `,` else print only 3rd field.